# showImagePicker and ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, uiimagepickercontroller

**edit 0**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.overlayViewController = [[BSsetupOverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSsetupOverlayViewController" bundle:nil] ;

    // as a delegate we will be notified when pictures are taken and when to dismiss the image picker
    self.overlayViewController.delegate = self;

    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        // camera is not on this device, don't show the camera button
        NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.myToolbar.items.count];
        [toolbarItems addObjectsFromArray:self.myToolbar.items];
        [toolbarItems removeObjectAtIndex:2];
        [self.myToolbar setItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];
    }

    [self showImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}
```

**edit 0**

The `-showImagePicker:` code below is almost exactly as copied from the PhotoPicker example, except that the **first** commented-out line is replaced by the line **above** it (because of a deprecated feature). However the new version of the line is producing the warning `Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x1c53ec70> on <BSsetupViewController: 0x1d888c10> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

On the other hand if I replace that **first** commented-out line with the one **below** it, I get the ARC Semantic issue `No visible @interface for 'BSsetupViewController' declares the selector 'presentModalViewController:animated:completion:'`

Any ideas?

```
- (void)showImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    if (self.imageView.isAnimating)
        [self.imageView stopAnimating];

    if (self.capturedImages.count > 0)
        [self.capturedImages removeAllObjects];

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType])
    {
        [self.overlayViewController setupImagePicker:sourceType];
        [self presentViewController:self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
      //[self presentModalViewController:self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES];
      //[self presentModalViewController:self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^(void){}];

    }
}
```

Comment: When you call this `showImagePicker` method, has the `self` view controller been displayed yet? The error indicates that it has not. The error about the 2nd line that is commented out is because there is no such method as `presentModalViewController:animated:completion:`.

Comment: I think it has been called. See the edited question where I added `-viewDidLoad:`, please.

Comment: just because the view controller's view has been loaded doesn't mean the view controller's view has been added to the view hierarchy yet. I suggest you move the call to `showImagePicker` to `viewDidAppear:` and see what happens.

Comment: The error message is no longer there. I still need to sort out what other parts of `viewDidLoad` needs to be put into `viewDidAppear`. For now they are mostly duplicates, but call to `showImagePicker` is only in `viewDidAppear`.  Thanks. I never would have figured that out on my own.